# Is it possible to compose ranges with minmax and join using |

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

Given the following example using ranges-v3:

```
using namespace ranges::views;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1 = {
    {1,  2,  3,  17, 5 },
    {11, 12, -1, 14, 15}
};

auto [min_val, max_val] = ranges::minmax(join(v1));
```

I can get the correct `minmax` value. But i am wondering if it is possible to use compose with values like `join` and `minmax`?

For eg. why can i not do this:

```
auto [min_val, max_val] = v1 | join() | ranges::minmax();
```

The compiler error is long and unwieldy, because i am compiling with c++17 and do not have concepts. But i was hoping to understand from the documentation [here](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) when i can and cannot use the `|` (compose) style.

Comment: Unlike `actions::sort`, `ranges::minmax` does not return a range, so this makes it impossible to connect new pipes after it, so it cannot be used as a pipe.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It cannot be used after? Like in the order i have given it?